# How to design LMS in PHP for executing a SCORM 1.2 package

Tags: php, scorm1.2

I've a SCORM V-1.2 package for which i want to build a LMS system in PHP.

Here is SCORM 1.2 package structure...

[image]

I know, LMS can interact with SCORM Object by using their API. But, my problem is i can't able to fig. out what should be the whole architecture of LMS system so that all these things can happen. I mean, do i need to write any code, in index.html(inside SCORM package) or some where else. I've done a lot of hit-n-trial but till now no luck. I can able to play the SCORM course but, can't able to communicate SCORM OBJ to any Server Side file so that i can track user activity & store in my DB.

I'd gone through this dev guide (http://www.scorm.com/wp-content/assets/cookbook/CookingUpASCORM_v1_2.pdf) But, really can't able to know how i should move forward.

Any thought... ?

Comment: You're going to be writing a bit of code.  White papers reference how to design/build the infrastructure.  You essentially are exposing a JavaScript "API" namespace which you will have to design to support SCORM 1.2 interface calls for the content to communicate with.  Much of SCORM 1.2 was optional so you have that going for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Read the official docs, they describe every piece of functionality in detail.

http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-version-1-2/

http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/SCORM-1-2-Specification?type=technical_documentation